# How do I call a component by a parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I call a component without this switch?
Something like:

```
<(route.id) navigator={navigator} />

    navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
      case 'First':
      return <First navigator={navigator} />
      case 'Second':
      return <Second navigator={navigator} />
      case 'Third':
      return <Third navigator={navigator} />
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `react-router`? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can check it out again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample solution

```
const FIELD_MAPPING = {
  First,
  Second,
  Third,
};


render() { 
  const ComponentField = FIELD_MAPPING[route.id] || DefaultComponentField;

  return <ComponentField navigator={navigator} />;
}
```

---

**Note**: Dynamic component names such as

```
const MyComponent = 'First'

return <MyComponent />
```

is not possible, since

```
return <MyComponent />
```

compiles to

```
return React.createElement(MyComponent, options);
```

> Capitalized types indicate that the JSX tag is referring to a React component. These tags get compiled into a direct reference to the named variable, so if you use the JSX  expression, Foo must be in scope.

Otherwise, the type is a string or not capitalized variable and interpreted as HTML tag.

```
React.createElement('div', options);
```

is equivalent to

```
const tag = 'div';
React.createElement(tag, options);
```